# Redirect to a specific tab on submit of text box via post using Flask/BootStrap/jquery

Tags: jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a webpage that contains 3 tabs on it. Tab 1 is the primary active tab. Tab 3 has Text box/Submit button pair. When I select the submit button on Tab 3 it redirects me to Tab 1. I need to get this to redirect me back to Tab 3.

I have attempted to utilize solutions like the following:

[How to redirect to a specific tab using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972042/how-to-redirect-to-a-specific-tab-using-jquery)

However, due to the way that Flask (which is the server I am using) performs template rendering it errors on me when I utilize the suggested solution saying that /page#tab3 is not a valid page (I can provide the actual error if that will help after I clean it up).

Here is the code I am using for the submission of the text (html page):

```
<div id="tabs">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width:98%">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#open" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="new" role="tab">Open Issues</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="reports" role="tab">New Issue</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#lookup" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="incidents" role="tab">Lookup</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" style="width:98%">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="open">

        <table class="table sortable" align="center" style="width:98%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th data-defaultsort="asc" width="10%"><center><center>Number</center></center></th>
        <th width="50%"><center>Subject</th>
        <th width="10%"><center>Owner</th>
        <th width="15%"><center>Updated</th>
        <th width="15%"><center>Created</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for content in array %}
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="10%">{{ content['number'] }}</a></td>
        <td align="center" width="50%">{{ content.Description }}</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%">{{ content['ID'] }} </td>
        <td> blank</td>
        <td> blank</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="lookup">
        {% if pagetype == "post" %}
                <p> This should be the redirect page</p>
        {% else  %}
                <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                  <label for="incident">Incident Lookup</label>
                  <input type="text" id="lookup1" name="incident" placeholder="Incident Number">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the Javascipt that I am importing:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap-sortable.js"</script>
```

Here are the contents of the Flask Server that is relevant to this issue (cleaned of course):

```
@app.route("/page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_auth
def page():
        pageType="issue"
        title = "Issue"
        issues = []
        issues_open = db.issues_open
        for post in issues_open.find():
                issues.append(post.copy())

        if request.method == 'POST':
                id = request.form['incident']
                app.logger.debug(id)
                pagetype="post"
                return render_template("page.html", id=id, pagetype=pagetype)

        return render_template("page.html", pageType=pageType, open_issues=issues, title=title)
```

If any more information or context is needed I am more than willing to provide but this should be enough to get the conversation started.

Answer (score 1):

after form submission redirect with unique keyword and put the condition in tab page if unique keyword is get then a particular tab class will be active and for this you have to use `jquery addClass() & removeClass()` methods...

Comment: So in the flask post function set a variable to True (for example) and in the code if that is true change the html of the displayed page to make the specific tab the "Active" tab?  
Am I understanding this correctly? If that is the case I don't see why I would have to use jquery for that (assuming it works).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out (I just had to look at the problem a different way).

Flask code didn't change.

HTML Code did though:

```
<div id="tabs">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width:98%">
    <li role="presentation" {% if pageType == "remedy" %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="#open" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="new" role="tab">Open Issues</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="reports" role="tab">New Issue</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" {% if pageType == "post" %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="#lookup" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="incidents" role="tab">Lookup</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" style="width:98%">
  {% if pageType == "post" %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="open">
  {% else %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="open">
  {% endif %}

        <table class="table sortable" align="center" style="width:98%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th data-defaultsort="asc" width="10%"><center><center>Number</center></center></th>
        <th width="50%"><center>Subject</th>
        <th width="10%"><center>Owner</th>
        <th width="15%"><center>Updated</th>
        <th width="15%"><center>Created</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for content in array %}
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="10%">{{ content['number'] }}</a></td>
        <td align="center" width="50%">{{ content.Description }}</td>
        <td align="center" width="10%">{{ content['ID'] }} </td>
        <td> blank</td>
        <td> blank</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    {% if pageType == "post" %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="lookup">
         <p> This should be the redirect page</p>
    {% else  %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="lookup">
        {% if pagetype == "post" %}
                <p> This should be the redirect page</p>
        {% else  %}
                <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                  <label for="incident">Incident Lookup</label>
                  <input type="text" id="lookup1" name="incident" placeholder="Incident Number">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This may not be the most elegant way to solve this problem but it works. If you have a solution you feel would be better please feel free to suggest.